# Changing speed value for all items in an Arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist of popcorn made by the following:

```
public class Popcorn
{
int posX;
int posY;
int speed;
int taps;

public Popcorn(int x, int y)
{
    posX = x;
    posY = y;
    speed = PowerConstants.popcorn_speed;
    taps = 0;
}

public void tick()
{
    posY += speed;
}

public int getX()
{
    return posX;
}

public int getY()
{
    return posY;
}

public void addTap()
{
    taps++;
}

public int getTaps()
{
    return taps;
}
}
```

I have different powerups I want to use on these popcorn, one of which involves making the popcorn fall faster down the screen (dealing therefore with the speed) for a certain amount of time. The powerup works (and so does the timing system); however, it only affects newly created popcorn, not the popcorn that are already on the screen. Here is the relevant code:

```
ArrayList <Popcorn> popcorns;
Image happyPopcorn;

popcorns = new ArrayList<Popcorn>();
happyPopcorn = Assets.happyPopcorn;

//This section is in the updateRunning() section of my code

if ((PowersScreen3.getDecodedChoice() == Assets.powerup_speedup && System.currentTimeMillis() - power_start_3 <= 10000) ||
            (PowersScreen2.getDecodedChoice() == Assets.powerup_speedup && System.currentTimeMillis() - power_start_2 <= 10000) ||
            (PowersScreen.getDecodedChoice() == Assets.powerup_speedup && System.currentTimeMillis() - power_start <= 10000)) {
 //The above if-state is just checking the timing system and deciding which powerup was chosen
        PowerConstants.popcorn_speed = 4;
        Log.d("Powerups", "all popcorn speed up");
    }
```

It makes sense that by changing the speed constant, the speed of the newly formed popcorn would change. However, I also want the current popcorn in the arraylist to change their speed as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `PopcornConstants.speed` directly in your calculations in the `Popcorn` class instead of an instance variable. Although calling something that changes a 'constant' is not the best of naming choices.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: **Don't** use `PopcornConstants.speed` directly in your calculations, because it is a **constant**, and should as such be immutable, as enforced by a `final` keyword. *Or* keep the code but rename the class, because the current name is misleading.